# Spring: calling method before injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, autowired

I will explain my problem with a simple example:

```java
public class A () {
    private B b;

    public A () { /* ... */ }

    public B getB () { /* ... */ }

    @Autowired
    public void setB (B b) { /* ... */ }

    public init (int x, int y, float rx, float ry) { /* ... */ }
}
```

and

```java
public class B () {
    private A a;

    public B () { /* ... */ }

    public A getA () { /* ... */ }

    @Autowired
    public void setA (A a) { /* ... */ }

    public init (int x, int y, float rx, float ry) { /* ... */ }
}
```

So I need call `init()` method before injection, because immediately after injection is called method from injected component in loop fps times per second, and of course is not initialized so I get `NullPointerException`.

I use setter injection and create object with `context.getBean("A")`.

Is there any way to call method `init()` before injection?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is `@Postconstruct`, specified in JSR250, which tells Spring to run the method as soon as the dependencies are injected into your bean.  You could also implement the `InitializingBean` interface.  Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean) for more details and options.  However, your circular dependency is going to complicate things.  There are a few ways to [solve this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-setter-injection), but at the end of the day you're almost always better off redesigning to remove the circular dependency.

Comment: thank you, but as you can see, I need call init() with parameters and in xml I dont know parameters .. is only local fields in method where I create A.